# how to get accuration xgboost in r

Tags: r, classification, xgboost

## how i get accuracy xgboost in r?

i have same problem, i will get a accuracy with method xgboost

````
library(xgboost)
library(RStoolbox)
library("caret", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
setwd("D:/NEW DATA/kurt/tugas")
shp <- shapefile("jajal/samplepoint(2).shp")
ras <- stack("cigudegc21.tif")

vals <- extract(ras,shp)
train<-data.matrix(vals)
classes <- as.numeric(as.factor(shp@data$id)) - 1
xgb <- xgboost(data = train, 
               label = classes, 
               eta = 0.1,
               max_depth = 4, 
               nround=100, 
               objective = "multi:softmax",
               num_class = length(unique(classes)),
               nthread = 3)
result   <- predict(xgb, ras[1:(nrow(ras)*ncol(ras))],reshape=TRUE)
res      <- raster(ras)
res      <- setValues(res,result+1)```
````

Comment: You can obtain accuracy of the prediction with confusionMatrix from caret. The code is as follows: confusionMatrix(prediction variable, reference variable)

Comment: Also `table(predicted,reference)` could help. The output is simpler than `caret::confusionMatrix()`.